# vue-spinner for page router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I use [vue-spinner](https://github.com/greyby/vue-spinner) and I have a [project on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/n4nkz3nl5p).

Main page is Home.vue with links on other components:

```
 <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
 <router-link to="/helloworld">Hello World</router-link>
 <router-link to="/bigimg">Big Img</router-link>
```

main.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";

import router from "./router";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  //loading = true;
  next();
});
```

I want to make loader like on [fishtripr.com](https://www.fishtripr.com/) website (vue website).

**Question:** How I can make vue website loader and How can make loader (vue-spinner) when moving from page to page (like `NProgress.start()` & `NProgress.done(`) )?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best way is to have a data property `loading` that is set to `true` (you can do this with a mixin) and then once the server has responded with the actual data you dismiss the loader by setting `this.loading = false`. I don't think you can put this logic inside the global `router.beforeEach` because it does not have access to the component. You would need to put the logic in the instance `beforeRouteUpdate`, which i don't think is ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You need a mix of `router.beforeEach` and of manually updating the variable as Justin mentioned. Probably something like vuex makes sense in this case since many components will be changing the data.

In your vuex store

```
  mutations: {
    resetLoading(state){
      state.isLoading = true
    },

    // This needs to be called on each component individually
    finishedLoading(state){
      state.isLoading = false
    },
    ..
```

Something like this for the router

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  store.commit("resetLoading")
  next()
})
```

And then in your component

```
  ..
  created(){
    var self = this
    this.$store.dispatch("fetchData").then(function(){
      self.$store.commit("finishedLoading")
    })
  },
  ..
```